# Rails 6.1 bootstrap CSS is incorrect after JS event handling

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I can't find where is the problem, I am using Rails 6.1 with webpacker and all dependencies seem to work healthy. test

I have a table with bootstrap styles on it and I want to sort this table by title, using vanilla JS but this what happens with my table after sorting:

[Table before sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgsLm.png)

[Table after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdRdb.png)

This is how my clumsy JS script looks like:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  let control = document.querySelector('.sort-by-title')

  if (control) control.addEventListener('click', sortRowsByTitle)
})

function sortRowsByTitle () {
  let table = document.querySelector('table')

// Choose all rows, create Array out of it and delete header row
  let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr')
  let sortedRows = Array.from(rows)
  sortedRows.shift()

// In this IF clause the way of sorting is chosen by checking the class of HTML element
  if (this.querySelector('.octicon-arrow-up').classList.contains('hide')) {
    sortedRows.sort(compareRowsAsc)
    this.querySelector('.octicon-arrow-up').classList.remove('hide')
    this.querySelector('.octicon-arrow-down').classList.add('hide')
  } else {
    sortedRows.sort(compareRowsDesc)
    this.querySelector('.octicon-arrow-up').classList.add('hide')
    this.querySelector('.octicon-arrow-down').classList.remove('hide')
  }

// Here is created new table, needed classes are added to it, 
// and afterwards sorted rows are appended to it
  let sortedTable = document.createElement('table')
  sortedTable.classList.add('table', 'table-light', 'table-hover', 'table-bordered', 'mt-2')


  sortedTable.appendChild(rows[0])

  for (let i = 0; i < sortedRows.length; i++) {
    sortedTable.appendChild(sortedRows[i])
  }

// Finally, old table replaced by sorted one in DOM
 
  table.parentNode.replaceChild(sortedTable, table)
}
```

So my DOM after sorting looks exactly the same, with all the classes, and CSS inspector has all the same properties there.

[DOM and CSS before sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKrm2.jpg)

[DOM and CSS after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQadT.jpg)